# Quartz-schedule.net getting schedule from trigger

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a trigger persisted to a database.  I need to be able to present the schedule back to the user so that they can see it or alter it.

How do I get a cron schedule from an TriggerKey

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group2")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?").Build();
```

Once the above is built, how do I get it back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already scheduled the job as described [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/jobs-and-triggers.html), you can retrieve the trigger for it like this:

```
var triggerKey = new TriggerKey("trigger3", "group2");
var trigger = scheduler.GetTrigger(triggerKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

First it must be added to the scheduler:

```
            var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();
            var job = JobBuilder.Create<ClassType>()
                        .Build();

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .WithIdentity("Your ID")
                        .StartNow()
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(simpleSchedule => simpleSchedule.WithRepeatCount(0))
                        .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

then you should be able to get the jobs and triggers like this:

```
var groups = scheduler.GetJobGroupNames();
var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggerGroupNames();
```

and you can remove items from the schedule with:

```
scheduler.DeleteJob(JobKey jobKey);
```